# Django rest framework serialize model with FK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm learning Django and Vue.js. There is something I'm not understanding how it works.

I have a model "Nc" which have some foreign key to other models like Affaire.

How can I obtain in my JSON files the **str** return for instances instead of the real value...

models.py :

```
class Affaires(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    cp = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    dessinateur = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    conducteur = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    chefdeprojet = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cloture = models.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'affaires'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.id, self.nom)

class NC(models.Model):
    idaffaire = models.ForeignKey(Affaires, models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="N° d'affaire", db_column='idAffaire')
    idof = models.ForeignKey(AffairesOfs, models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="N° d'OF", db_column='idOf')
    idposte = models.ForeignKey(ProductionPostes, models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="Poste", db_column="idPoste")
    idrepere = models.ForeignKey(AffairesReperes, models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="Repère", db_column='idRepere')
    idnc = models.ForeignKey(Nc_type, models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="Type de NC", db_column='idNc_type')
    quantite = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Quantité")
    dateajout = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date d'ajout", db_column='dateAjout')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'qualite_Nc'
```

serialize.py

```
class NcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class  Meta:
        model = NC
        fields = '__all__'
```

JSON files :

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "quantite": 1,
        "dateajout": "2020-04-08",
        "idaffaire": 1145,
        "idof": 1433,
        "idposte": 6271,
        "idrepere": 5361,
        "idnc": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "quantite": 17,
        "dateajout": "2020-04-09",
        "idaffaire": 1205,
        "idof": 1290,
        "idposte": 5812,
        "idrepere": 7004,
        "idnc": 1
    },
```

The result I want on JSON :

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "quantite": 1,
        "dateajout": "2020-04-08",
        "idaffaire": 1145 - CORTIS,
        "idof": 1433,
        "idposte": 6271,
        "idrepere": 5361,
        "idnc": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "quantite": 17,
        "dateajout": "2020-04-09",
        "idaffaire": 1205 - GS Cergy,
        "idof": 1290,
        "idposte": 5812,
        "idrepere": 7004,
        "idnc": 1
    },
```

I'm not sure the issue is to have **str** return on the JSON file. In fact I don't understand how I'm supposed to use Serialize with FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a serializer for each of your foreign objects.

I would personally remove all the prefix `id` from `idaffaire` and so on from the model `NC`, because you are able to do something like `instance.affaire.id` and `instance.idaffaire.id` does not make much sense.

code sample:

```py
class AffairesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class  Meta:
        model = Affaires
        fields = '__all__'

class NcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    affaire = AffairesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class  Meta:
        model = NC
        fields = '__all__'
```

Make sure you use `select_related('affaire')` when you create you queryset to avoid unnecessary requests to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`serializers.StringRelatedField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) field as,

```
class NcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    idaffaire = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = NC
        fields = '__all__'
```